# How can I limit the available choices for a foreign key field in a django modelformset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Application: 
This is a workshop proposal system for a conference. A user can create presenters and workshops, and link them together. Each user should only have access to the presenters and workshops that s/he created/owns.

```
# Models:

class Workshop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, db_index=True)
    presenters = models.ManyToManyField("Presenter", through="WorkshopPresenter")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Presenter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, db_index=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class WorkshopPresenter(models.Model):
    workshop = models.ForeignKey("Workshop")
    presenter = models.ForeignKey("Presenter")
    cardinality = models.IntegerField()
```

To link presenters to workshops, the user is directed to a workshop-specific page, containing a modelformset for `WorkshopPresenter`. Workshop and cardinality are set by the view after the formset is filled out, so the user only sees a list of dropdowns with possible presenter names.
[Image of the association page](http://i878.photobucket.com/albums/ab347/modulatrix/association.png)

**Question**: How can I make it so the presenter dropdowns on this association page only contain presenters who are owned by the current user? The dropdowns should only contain the results of `Presenter.objects.filter(owner__exact=request.user)`. Currently they contain *all* presenters.

```
# View snippet that creates the formset:

workshop = Workshop.objects.filter(owner__exact=request.user).get(id=workshop_id)

MyWorkshopPresenterFormSet = modelformset_factory(WorkshopPresenter, 
                                                  formset=WorkshopPresenterFormSet, 
                                                  extra=5, 
                                                  exclude = ("workshop","cardinality"))
formset = MyWorkshopPresenterFormSet(request.POST or None,
                                     queryset=workshop.workshoppresenter_set.all())
```

`WorkshopPresenterFormSet` just extends `BaseModelFormSet` and does some custom validation, nothing fancy.

I've seen some solutions out there that work for regular forms, but nothing to work with modelformsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically change the queryset on a form using functional methods (curry), closures, or callbacks.  See all three methods in the first three answers to "[passing custom form parameters to formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset)."

Also see James Bennetts post "[So you want a dynamic form](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/)" for a nice in-depth discussion of the closure method.

Comment: Took me a while to really get this clean, but the James Bennett link is very good. Ended up creating a getWorkshopPresenterForm(request.user) function that dynamically defines and returns a form class specific for that user.