# same form, different variables. how to implement?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a table where one of the fields is categories: Sports, Movies, Books, etc
I have another table with sub-categories, for instance sports is divided into ballet, futebol, golf, etc, and so on.

Let's say I've a list with two variables : ['Sport', 'Movies']
(These variables came from a file. I'm doing an upload file, and every time the category has more than one sub-option, I want to show a select with the option inside the category.)

for instance, the user inserted sport and movies. I want to show a select option for each one of the field inside the list. But the sub-options are not the same, it depends on the category chosen.

Output:

Sport:
  o Futebol
  o Ballet
  o Golf

Movies:
  o Drama
  o Comedy

forms.py

```
class OptionsForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, numb, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OptionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['num'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), choices=
        numb, label="", required=True)
```

I'm passing a tuple with all the sub-options:

```
numb = (('ballet', 'ballet'),
       ('futebol', 'futebol'),
       ('golf', 'golf'),  
       ('drama', 'drama'),
       ('comedy', 'comedy'))
```

but I'm not sure how to distinguish them, perhaps with formsets this will work, not sure how although

Any help or suggestion would be appreciate!
Thanks

Comment: You need two selects: one has [Sport, Movies] choices and second changes its choices according to the value of the first, right?

Comment: correct, i need two select but differently. let me update my question with more details, if you have more doubts ask..

Comment: Hope it's easier to interpret, basically I want two selects (could be more or less), one for sports and another for movies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was more easy than I was expected :)

I just needed to pass a dictionary of tuples:

```
dic = { 'Sport': [('ballet', 'ballet'), ('futebol', 'futebol'), ('golf'), ('golf')],
        'Movies': [('drama', 'drama'), ('comedy', 'comedy')] }
```

and change forms:

```
class CategoriesForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, numb, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CtaegoriesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for p, i in numb.items():
            self.fields[p] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), choices=i,
                required=True)
```