# Pre-fill data in individual formset forms with modelformset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to generate an "update formset" to update a large number of instances in one go, where the updated field is empty in the database (at the time of rendering the update formset) but is "suggested" using an already filled-in field.

My model goes here:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    plan_start_time = models.TimeField()
    actual_start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

So what I'd like is a table where `actual_start_time` is suggesting `plan_start_time` as pre-filled (initial) value.

**What I tried:**

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['actual_start_time'].initial = self.fields['plan_start_time']  # doesn't work 
        self.fields['actual_start_time'].initial = "08:00" # doesn't work either
        self.fields['actual_start_time'].initial = datetime.time(hour=8)  # doesn't work...
        self.initial['actual_start_time'] = self.fields['plan_start_time'] # this puts '<django.forms.fields.TimeField object at 0x067BA330>' in the field... not its value

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('plan_start_time', 'actual_start_time', )

# Specifying form to use
MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(Event, extra=0, fields=('plan_start_time', 'actual_start_time'), form=EventForm)
```

I guess the question comes down to: can I access a form field **value** in the `__init__()` of the form? 
If not, what would be a workaround for this issue?

As an alternative, I'm looking into rendering `plan_start_time` as a hidden field and then copying it over to the `actual_start_time` fields for every field in my table, using Javascript. But I'd be surprised if there would be no Django client side way to do this, so would like to avoid JS for now.

Using Django 1.8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897756/different-initial-data-for-each-form-in-a-django-formset

Comment: Thanks @ShangWang, I had a look at that one, but it doesn't seem to cover my use case. I want to pre-fill data dependent on another field. Furthermore I'm wondering why the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by providing a `form` to use in the `modelformset_factory` and overriding `__init__()` the proper way. Using `self.instance`, the object's existing form value can be accessed:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.instance.actual_start_time:
        self.initial['actual_start_time'] = self.instance.plan_start_time
```