# Initialize Django model formset additional form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have following definition for `ModelFormset`:

```
class MyModelDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MyModel.STATUS)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id']


MyModelDetailsFormset = modelformset_factory(
    MyModel,
    form=MyModelDetailsForm,
    extra=0)
```

And this is how I'm creating instance in `get_context_data`

```
formset = MyModelDetailsFormset(queryset=self.my_models)
```

If I'll initialize `status` fields this way:

```
for form in formset:
    form.fields['status'].initial = get_initial_value()
```

everything works.

If I'd like to do something like this (following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23497278):

```
formset = MyModelDetailsFormset(queryset=self.my_models, initial=[{'status':1},{'status':2}])
```

initial values don't kick-in. What I mean is that this:

```
for form in formset:
   print(form.fields['status'].initial)
```

prints `None`

Why is that happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I see mistake I've made. According to `documentation`:

> However, with model formsets, the initial values only apply to extra forms, those that aren’t attached to an existing model instance.

In other words there seems to be no way to initialize those values with initial dictionary.