# How do I construct a Django form with model objects in a Select widget?

Tags: django

Let's say I'm using the Django Site model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My Site values are (key, value):

```
1. Stackoverflow
2. Serverfault
3. Superuser
```

I want to construct a form with an html select widget with the above values:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Stackoverflow</option>
    <option value="2">Serverfault</option>
    <option value="3">Superuser</option>
</select>
```

I'm thinking of starting with the following code but it's incomplete:

```
class SiteForm(forms.Form):
    site = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select())
```

Any ideas how I can achieve that with Django form?

**EDIT**

Different pages will present different site values.  A dev page will show development sites while a cooking page will show recipe sites.  I basically want to dynamically populate the widget choices based on the view. I believe I can achieve that at the moment by manually generating the html in the template.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`ModelChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

UPDATE: Especially note the [`queryset`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) argument. In the view that is backing the page, you can change the `QuerySet` you provide based on whatever criteria you care about.

Comment: Can I specify the queryset in the view?

Comment: As in, provide the `QuerySet` to use whenever you instantiate your `Form`? I'm not sure. If your possibilities are limited, it seems fairly straightforward to provide a `Form` subclass tailored to the specific view you're using, e.g., `DeveloperSitesForm`, `EndUserSitesForm`, etc.

Comment: I was able to do it from the code in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset

Answer (score 15):

I haven't tested this, but I'm thinking something along the lines of...

```
site = forms.IntegerField(
    widget=forms.Select(
        choices=Site.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
        )
     )
```

Edit --

I just tried this out and it does generate the choices correctly.  The `choices` argument is expecting a list of 2-tuples like this...

```
(
   (1, 'stackoverflow'),
   (2, 'superuser'),
   (value, name),
)
```

The `.values_list` will return that exact format provided you have the ID and the name/title/whatever as so:  `.values_list('id', 'name')`.  When the form is saved, the value of `.site` will be the id/pk of the selected site.

Comment: This will evaluate the Site queryset when the form is first defined. If the data changes, the form won't show the new data.