# Django formset : POST formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem with django formset. I want to validate one field in the formset. I followed these links 
[Django Passing Custom Form Parameters to Formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset)

and able to create the forms.

but how can i POST my data to formset.

this is my form

```
class BookingDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    age = forms.IntegerField()

   def __init__(self, trip, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookingDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        age = self.fields["age"]
        trip = trip
        print "This prints when formset is created"
    def clean_age(self):
        // want some checking here
        #raise ValidationError('Error msg')
        return self.cleaned_data['age']
```

and my view is

```
formset = formset_factory(BookingDetailsForm, extra=number_of_peoples)
formset.form = staticmethod(curry(BookingDetailsForm, trip))
// above two line is working perfectly
```

Then How can I POST My formset??

```
formset = formset_factory(BookingDetailsForm, trip, request.POST)// not working
```

and after posting i want to check age field in clean method.

Answer (score 3):

```
formset_class = formset_factory(BookingDetailsForm, extra=number_of_peoples)
formset_class.form = staticmethod(curry(BookingDetailsForm, trip))
formset = formset_class(request.POST)
```