# django formset issue

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have 2 models

```
class A(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)


class B(models.Model):
   id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   user=models.ForeignKey(A)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=200)


#forms.py
class BForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=B
        fields=('name','user')
    def __init__(self,user_name,*args,**kwargs):
       super(BForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       if user_name:
          self.field['user']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=A.objects.filter(name__icontains=user_name)


#views.py

def myview(request,user_name):
    formset=formset_factory(BForm(user_name=user_name),extra=10)
```

I am getting following error

'BForm' object has no attribute '**name**'

Actually i only want only selective value of class A to shown in my formset

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

Firstly, the `__init__` method form the `BForm` class looks wrong. `user_name` is a keyword argument, but below you have the condition `if user`, without defining user anywhere.

Secondly, you can't initialise the form with the `user_name` argument when defining the formset. It looks like you are trying to do the same as in the stack overflow question [Passing Custom Form Parameters to Formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset).

Thirdly, please supply the entire traceback. Only including one line of the traceback,

`'BForm' object has no attribute 'name'`

makes it harder to track down where the problem is.