# Django: Saving with "Unique Together" and Deleting objects via inlineformset causes error pages

Tags: django, forms, django-models, inline-formset

Sorry if this is a simple fix, I am having 2 issues with my inlineformset:

1. Saving an invalid object (does not meet unique together requirement) throws an error page rather than displaying the errors in the form.

   At one point I had my errors displaying correctly when saving an invalid object, but when I tried to save a valid object I would get an error saying that membership.department was null. Which is why I put the "for instance in instances" but now I get this new issue of not displaying errors when saving a invalid object.
2. I have the same issue when deleting a valid object. The object gets deleted as it should, but I still get an error page...

I am at a lost.

When saving invalid objects I get:

```
The Membership could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

When deleting valid objects I get:

```
[u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']
```

MODEL:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("project", "employee",),)
```

VIEW.py

```
def employee_edit(request, employee_id):
    i = get_object_or_404(Employee, pk=employee_id)
    MembershipForm = make_membership_form(i)
    MembershipFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Employee, Membership, exclude='department', extra=1, form=MembershipForm)
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = MembershipFormSet(request.POST, instance=i)
        if f.is_valid():
            instances = f.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.department = i.department
                instance.save()
            f.save_m2m()
            return render_to_response('dbtest/edit.html', {'item': i, 'formset': f, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        f = MembershipFormSet(instance=i)
    return render_to_response('dbtet/edit.html', {'item': i, 'formset': f, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def make_membership_form(i):
    class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
        project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.filter(department=i.department))
        class Meta:
            model = Membership
            exclude = ('department', 'employee')
            unique_together = (("project", "employee",),)
    return MembershipForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message is pretty straight forward.

```
The Membership could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

You are saving the formset without checking first that it's valid. You should only call save if `formset.is_valid()` is true. Have another look at [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743103/django-how-to-limit-field-choices-in-formset)

Comment: so i reedited my question to reflect your previous answer but I still get an error page when membership doesnt validate instead of errors showing up in the forum...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you changed from an inline model formset to a regular model formset - only that you sort out the bit where you check the formset is valid and save. What error do you get now? Note that `unique_together = (("project", "employee",),)` won't do anything in the model form - it's an option for models only.

Comment: Changing it back to an inline model formset, the errors show up when the the object is invalid. it saves a valid object too. but the delete a valid object is still an issue for me. I've updated my code.

Comment: Don't call `f.save()` again after looping through your instances. You do need `f.save_m2m()` if there are any many to many relationships that need to be updated.