# cant pass initial values to a formset using curry

Tags: django, forms, formsets

as per this SO question [Django Passing Custom Form Parameters to Formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset) im tryin to use curry to pass a dictionary of initial values to my formset.

its not working, it gives me a formset of empty values, which isn't what its supposed to do.

can anyone see if im implementing this wrong?

```
data = {'supplier': input_data['supplier'],}

InstanceFormSet = formset_factory(BulkAddInstanceForm, extra=int(input_data['copies']))
InstanceFormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(BulkAddInstanceForm, data))
```

EDIT: as requested

```
class BulkAddInstanceForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BulkAddInstanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['supplier'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Supplier.objects.all(),
            label='Supplier',
            empty_label='Select a Supplier...',
            required=True,
        )
        self.fields['syllabus'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Syllabus.objects.all(),
            label='Syllabus',
            empty_label='Select a Syllabus...',
            widget=FilterWidget(
                queryset=Syllabus.objects.all(),
                parent_queryset=Supplier.objects.all(),
                control_name='supplier',
                parent_attr='supplier',
            ),
            required=False,
        )
        self.fields['venue'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Venue.objects.all(),
            label='Venue',
            empty_label='Select a Venue...',
            widget=FilterWidget(
                queryset=Venue.objects.all(),
                parent_queryset=Supplier.objects.all(),
                control_name='supplier',
                parent_attr='supplier',
            ),
            required=False,
        )
    start_date = NiceDateField(required=False, label='Start Date')
    residential = forms.BooleanField(label='Res?', required=False)
    special_offers = forms.BooleanField(label='S/O?', required=False)
    manual_price = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    manual_cost = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

edit2: FAO Brandon

I have looked at the docco and it suggests to do a different thing.

```
formset = formset_factory(BulkAddInstanceForm, extra=int(input_data['copies']))
formset = InstanceFormSet(initial=[data, ])
```

which creates a formset with 'copies' amount of forms, plus another one with the data in.
if i do this

```
formset = InstanceFormSet(initial=[data, data])
```

then i get two extra forms with the data in.
so my idea is i need an iterator to add 'copies' number of dictionaries and zero the initial number of forms in the formset.

not that i know how to cod that yet!!

Comment: Can we see your BulkAddInstanceForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to do it with the following code:

```
InstanceFormSet = formset_factory(BulkAddInstanceForm, extra=0)
# build the list for populating the forms
    n, datalist = 0, []
    while n < int(input_data['copies']):
        datalist.append(data)
        print datalist
        n +=1

    formset = InstanceFormSet(initial=datalist)
```

so i create the formset, then i create a list of the data dictionaries, then populate the formset with the inital data as a list.

seems to be working so far, though i've got to work out how to collect and submit the info yet .

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pick up the value you're passing in during the `__init__`

When I've used this in the past, I've set up the parameter as such:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = data
        #do whatever else I need to do with data

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: I've tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work for the dynamic fields wher the value is wiped out when its initialised with a query set later.

I have successfully re-populated the same form where it exists on its own rather than as part of a formset by passing a dict of initial data. i just need to know why my code which is similar to the article linked isn't working.

Comment: Are you just trying to supply an initial value for the "supplier" field? or?

Comment: ive got a dictionary of fields to fill. basically, im building a bulk add feature. user visits and fills out the template form, then the view will refill the template form with the choices and also build a formset filled with the choices and  some additional options.

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset ?