# ModelChoiceField on a Foreign Key not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a foreign key inside a model and I want to customize the way it appears in my form. By default a select appears with option values as id. I want to change the option values to be another field.

Models.py:

```
class PriceDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(SizeOd, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

```
class SizeOd(models.Model):
    size = models.DecimalField(unique=True, decimal_places=1, max_digits=5)
    multiplier = models.DecimalField(unique=True, decimal_places=3, max_digits=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.size)
```

Forms.py:

```
class PriceDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SizeOd.objects.order_by('size'), to_field_name="multiplier", required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = PriceDetails
        exclude = ('id',)
```

Views.py:

```
class PriceDetailsInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = models.PriceDetails
    form = forms.PriceDetailsForm
    fields = '__all__'
    factory_kwargs = {'extra': 1, 'can_delete': False}

class CreateInvoiceView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = models.Invoice
    form = forms.InvoiceForm
    inlines = [PriceDetailsInline]
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'app/invoice_form.html'
```

Template:invoice_form.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <div id="FormSet" class="my_inline">
        {% for formset in inlines %}
            <table id="FormSet{{ formset.prefix }}{{ forloop.counter }}">
                {{ formset.as_table }}
            </table>
            {{ formset.management_form }}

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Invoice" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    {% for formset in inlines %}
        $('table#FormSet{{ formset.prefix }}{{ forloop.counter }}').formset();
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

Default:

```
<select>
<option value='id1'>size1</option>
<option value='id2'>size2</option>
</select>
```

Expected:

```
<select>
<option value='*multiplier1*'>size1</option>
<option value='multiplier2'>size2</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: [My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkPOS.png)
The option values here are ids, I want them to be multiplers.
ModelChoiceField does not make any changes. The select box (size field) appears the same if I eliminate 'size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SizeOd.objects.order_by('size'), to_field_name="multiplier", required=False)' altogether. Instead, it should sort the display text on select box according to size and append multipliers as values.

Comment: Can you provide your template please?!

Comment: `multiplier` isn't a unique field, so you shouldn't use that anyway. But tell us what you see. "it is not working" isn't a good enough description of the problem. Also we need the template.

Comment: Added template and provided more detail on the question in the bottom. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500795/how-can-i-change-the-queryset-of-one-of-the-fields-in-the-form-im-passing-to-in).
The problem was not with the ModelChoiceField. None of the changes made in forms.py was reflected in the forms. (because of the use of InlineFormSetFactory)
Overwrote construct_inlines() (which is part of extra_views.advanced.ModelFormWithInlinesMixin) in views.py

```
class CreateInvoiceView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateWithInlinesView):
model = models.Invoice
form = forms.InvoiceForm
inlines = [PriceDetailsInline]
fields = '__all__'
template_name = 'app/invoice_form.html'
def construct_inlines(self):
    inline_formsets = super(CreateInvoiceView, self).construct_inlines()
    inline_formsets[0].forms[0].fields['size'].queryset = models.SizeOd.objects.order_by('size')
    inline_formsets[0].forms[0].fields['size'].to_field_name = 'multiplier'
    return inline_formsets
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the model's appearance in forms by changing the return field

```
class PriceDetails(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.size) # <--change this here from .id --> .size
```

**Edited**