# Django Passing Custom Form Parameters to modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624013/237690) answer regarding formset_factory, I tried to do the same thing for modelformset_factory:

```
from django.utils.functional import curry
from functools wraps

AccountMemberFormSetBase = modelformset_factory(AccountMember,
                                                form=wraps(AccountMemberLimitedModelForm)(curry(AccountMemberLimitedModelForm, affiliate="test")),
                                                extra=2)
```

This throws the following error:

```
function() argument 1 must be code, not str
Exception Location: ../django/forms/models.py in modelform_factory, line 528
```

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Could you show the full traceback? Also, what django version are you using?

Comment: Django 1.6 - will post the full traceback soon

Comment: Here is the full traceback: http://pastebin.com/htt0ANFi

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same situation today.

See my comment in [Django Passing Custom Form Parameters to Formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset/25766319#25766319) for details and a workaround (I hope a link to StackOverflow itself is acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

```
class AccountMemberLimitedModelForm(forms.Form):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         affiliate = kwargs.pop('affiliate')
...         super(AccountMemberLimitedModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



AccountMemberFormSetBase = formset_factory(AccountMemberLimitedModelForm)
    formset = AccountMemberFormSetBase(form_kwargs={'affiliate': "test"})
```

Comment: It would be nice if you posted more than just some code. Perhaps you could explain why that code works?

Comment: with kwargs.pop('affiliate') I add external variable to the form. It must be done before calling super(AccountMemberLimitedModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) to take effect. 
And when I pass the variable to form from formset by using form_kwargs dictionary

Comment: You can get more information from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms