# Field added to django model form not populated by modified queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model form, to which I have added one extra field - is_flagged.

```
#forms.py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    is_flagged = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username','is_flagged']
```

Now, because my user model does not have an attribute of 'is_flagged', I create this value for each user via a modified queryset.

```
#managers.py
class FlaggedUserManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(FlaggedUserManager, self).get_queryset().all()
        for user in qs:
            user.is_flagged = True
        return qs

#user model
flagged_users = FlaggedUserManager()
```

Next, I create a modelformset using my custom queryset to populate the form.

```
base_formset = modelformset_factory(CustomUser, form=UserForm, extra=0)
formset = base_formset(queryset=CustomUser.flagged_users.all())
return {'formset': formset}
```

Everything works as expected, the field 'is_flagged' is rendered for all the users but the data isn't populating the form as the checkboxes rendered are all set to 0.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, and how I might be able to populate this field from a modified queryset?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just wondering but what would happen if you modified your template to reflect something like this:

`{% if user.is_flagged %}
 <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked></input>
 {% else %}
 <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" ></input>
 {% endif %}`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would work although it looks like i might not have time to try.  I solved this whole problem different by passing arguments to the formset.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in the end I solved this by approaching it in another way and passing arguments into the formset:

[Django Passing Custom Form Parameters to Formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset/25915489#25915489)