# What is a _curried method in python and how are they generated?

Tags: python, django

> Apologies upfront if this is a dupe; I search for "_curried python" and got 14 results, and then simply _curried" and that only bumped up to 33 results, and none seemed to help out...

The problem: I came across what I originally thought was a typo in our codebase today, here is the suspect:

```
student.recalculate_gpa()
```

Now, I suspect it to be a typo because `student` is an instance of a `Student` class that has no `recalculate_gpa` method. However, it does have a `calculate_gpa` method:

```
class Student(User):
    ...
    def calculate_gpa(self):
        # some calculations...
```

(Where `User` is the standard django user class.) But, *the code wasn't erroring*, which made no sense to me. So I did an inspect and found this:

```
... (a bunch of methods)
('calculate_gpa', <unbound method Student.calculate_gpa>),
... (some more methods)
('recalculate_gpa', <unbound method Student._curried>),
```

Strange, `recalculate_gpa` *is* in fact a method. But where on earth does it come from? I grep'd for "_curried" in our codebase and found nothing, so this must be some Django-related behavior. Certainly I would expect that somewhere in our project we've described how dynamically named functions are formed since `recalculate` seems like a plausible derivative of `calculate`, but I honestly have no idea where to start looking.

Thus, my question: how are curried methods like the one above generated, and where should I start looking to discover how our own codebase is curry-ing?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: What is the `User` you're inheriting from?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's the standard django User class

Comment: Is there a class decorator or anything?

Comment: no decorators around Student

Comment: This is Django-related, not "built-in Python behaviour" - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/functional.py#L13

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. If you have more "answer" information to post, it's perfectly fine to add a self-answer even though you accepted Joran's answer. Adding it to the question is just messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a curried method is when you partially call a method in advance of actually calling it

for example

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import count
def my_pow(x,y):
    return x**y

curried_pow2n = partial(my_pow,x=2)

for i in count(0): #print the 2**i
    print curried_pow2n(i)
```

you could also easily implement it with lambda

```
curried_pow2n = lambda x:return my_pow(2,x)
```

**although Im not sure this has anything to do with your actual question** ...

django also provides a curry method that is pretty similar to functools.partial

```
from django.utils.functional import curry    

lols = {'lols':'lols'}
formset = modelformset_factory(MyModel, form=myForm, extra=0)
formset.form = staticmethod(curry(MyForm, lols=lols))
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25915489/541038)

so you may want to look for `Student.recalculate_gpa =`

or perhaps in the `Student.__init__` method for `self.recalculate_gpa =`

you likely would not find it looking for `def recalculate_gpa`

Comment: Well here's the crazy thing, when I grep for "recalculate_gpa" across the entire project there is exactly one hit: the method call `student.recalculate_gpa()`

Comment: what if you grep `curry` (there may be some trickery in creating it) (are you sure you grepped the entire project also?)

Comment: Only "curry" instances are in our JS files - totally unrelated - ok... time for some tea and regrouping...

Comment: are you overloading `__getattr__` or something weird like that? I guarantee that django is not magically adding a `recalculate_gpa` method to your class

Comment: Try: `[cell.cell_contents for cell in Student.recalculate_gpa.__closure__]` to see what function has been wrapped and with what arguments.

Comment: Oh man that is genious! turns out it was a third party doing the trickery: https://github.com/aquameta/django-cached-field/blob/master/django_cached_field/__init__.py#L123 related to a different field - I'll have to just write up my own answer to explain everything... holy heck what a trace!

Comment: I knew for sure that it wasnt magic :P ... @QuentinDonnellan ... careful on posting your own answer if it is too targeted to your very specific problem other people likely wont find it helpful

Comment: Thank this is very helpful!  Evryone who is facing ```ImportError: cannot import name 'curry' from 'django.utils.functional'``` this error, you can replace curry method with "partial" from "functools". Just import partial method as mentioned in this answer and replace curry with partial() wherever its getting used. Since django have removed this package in latest version. Partial works exactly the similar way!!