# How to instantiate a field of a formset to pre-populate?

Tags: django, django-forms, populate, formset, formsets

My views allows me now to see if I have two questions, it shows me 2 forms. I wish I could now instantiate my 2 forms with one question each. So that the user no longer has simply answer the question without selecting ...

> My views. py :

```
def access(request, instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)
    formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Reply.objects.none())
        if formset.is_valid():
            new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for new_instance in new_instances:
                new_instance.user = logged_user
                new_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baseVisite/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Le formulaire est incorrecte !')
            return render_to_response('polls/error.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
     'formset': formset,
     'questions':questions,
     'logged_user':logged_user,
     'numPages' : numPages
     })
```

> my models.py :

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

> and my forms.py :

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        exclude = ('user','creationDate')
```

**I would like to pre-populate fields "questions" with this filter --> Question.objects.filter(page=instance) Is it possible to put a filter like this?**

Comment: Have tried to look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset

Comment: I just look but I do not think this corresponds to pre-populate

Answer (score -1):

You can use the queryset argument

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset

Comment: Please also include here an example of how to use. The link get unavailable in time.