# Django - Passing Custom Form Parameters to modelfactory

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I have a Django ModelForm like this:

```
class ContactPhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactPhoneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #....
```

...and a view where I try to get a respective formset:

```
ContactPhoneFormSet = modelformset_factory(ContactPhone,
                                           ContactPhoneForm, 
                                           extra=1, 
                                           can_delete = True)
```

Now, I want an additional parameter to be passed to the `__init__`method of the form:

```
 class ContactPhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, contact_id, *args, **kwargs):    
            self.contact_id = contact_id
            super(ContactPhoneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #....
```

I tried to the rewrite my view according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset):

```
ContactPhoneFormSet = modelformset_factory(ContactPhone,
                                           wraps(ContactPhoneForm)(partial(ContactPhoneForm, contact_id=contact_id)), 
                                           extra=1, 
                                           can_delete = True)
```

but I end up with `TypeError: the first argument must be callable` error. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.9 added a form_kwargs arguement so you should be able to do:

```
ContactPhoneFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    ContactPhone, ContactPhoneForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
formset = ContactPhoneFormSet(form_kwargs={'contact_id': contact_id})
```

Comment: Wow :) Thank you. Maybe you should post your answer here as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622982/django-passing-custom-form-parameters-to-formset).
And just for the future - can you think of the place you came to know this info ?